# Clarifying Clojure "Use as" semantics

Tags: clojure

The effect of `(use '[clojure.string :as str])` seems to be loading everything from clojure.string into the current namespace without namespace qualification. The effect of `(use '[clojure.string :as str :only (join)])` seems to be loading only join into the current namespace, making the rest of the clojure.string namespace accessible with the `str/` prefix. Is there any way to simply make the whole clojure.string namespace accessible with the `str/` prefix without selecting any names that I want to directly import into the current namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` is the preferred method for referring to other namespaces. You use `:as` to give a prefix for the namespace you're requiring. You can use `:refer` to refer specific symbols into the namespace without needing to be qualified. If you want to import all symbols into the namespace, you can use `:all` in place of the symbol names, although its use should be limited.

`use` is not used so much anymore and is avoided because it makes it harder to understand where an unqualified symbol is coming from. I didn't even realise `use` could provide an `:as`, it's not listed on the doc string.

Answer (score 0):

Note that different formats used in Clojure source code files vs at the REPL, which can be confusing if you get them mixed up.  In a source code file, the `ns` macro is used:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [clojure.string    :as str]
            [datomic.api       :as d] ))
```

so we use the `:require` *keyword* (with the colon), and the namespace specifcation vectors are unquoted.  Compare to what you need to type at the repl:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])
```

where we invoke the `require` *function* (without a colon), and must therefore quote the namespace specification vector.